# Do I need to run MediaPlayer in a service in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-service

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/ranjithnaidu/AudioRecorder) .

Maybe it's a long time operation when I use the `MediaRecorder` control, so the author run `MediaRecorder` in a service, you can see Code B.

Maybe it's a long time operation to play a audio too, so I think the author should run `MediaPlayer` in a service, but why doesn't Code A do that?

**Code A**

```
public final class MediaPlayerHolder implements PlayerAdapter {

    public static final int PLAYBACK_POSITION_REFRESH_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;

    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    
    @Override
    public void play() {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && !mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            if (mPlaybackInfoListener != null) {
                mPlaybackInfoListener.onStateChanged(PlaybackInfoListener.State.PLAYING);
            }
            startUpdatingCallbackWithPosition();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
public class RecordingService extends Service {
    
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public RecordingService getService() {
            return RecordingService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return myBinder;
    }

 
    public void startRecording(int duration) {
        setFileNameAndPath();
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilePath);

        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(duration); // set the max duration, after which the Service is stopped
        mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(192000);

       ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) is to have your code run on the background, you can do operations that don't require a user interface and even have your code run beyond the onDestoy() method of an activity. This is how music players allow you to listen to music even after you have closed the Application's Activity.

There are 3 types of services:

[Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)

[Background Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingAService)

[Bound Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

Why is Code B in a Service but Code A is not?

From the Bound services overview:

> A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. It allows
> components (such as activities) to bind to the service, send requests,
> receive responses, and perform interprocess communication (IPC). A
> bound service typically lives only while it serves another application
> component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

In other words it allows communication with other applications or across separate processes. And that's the main reason the author would use the Service. It has nothing to do with performance.

About performance:

Code B does not account for performance.

From the [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) overview:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the
> service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
> process unless you specify otherwise. You should run any blocking
> operations on a separate thread within the service to avoid
> Application Not Responding (ANR) errors.

So merely using a Service does not guarantee performance. In Code B we have the method startRecording(), which initializes MediaRecorder and sets some paramaters for the Recording. This doesn't not mean that this method will run as soon as the service starts. The Author has used a Bound Service, you can tell by the method:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
}
```

Which means that any component that binds to it (such as an activity or another process can call its method startRecording() ). Please check the Bound Service link for more info. In the project this gets called from RecordViewModel.startRecording().

If you are worried about performance. Code B should start a new Thread inside startRecording(int duration). There are many ways to do it. Here is one:

```
public void startRecording(int duration) {

( new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                

            setFileNameAndPath();
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFilePath);

            mRecorder.setMaxDuration(duration); // set the max duration, after which the Service is stopped
            mRecorder.setAudioChannels(1);
            mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(192000);

       ...



        }

    }) ).start();


}
```

As for Code A the only thing happening there is the call to MediaPlayer.start(), which already starts a new thread internally.

From the MediaPlayer class source code:

```
public void start() throws IllegalStateException {
        //FIXME use lambda to pass startImpl to superclass
        final int delay = getStartDelayMs();
        if (delay == 0) {
            startImpl();
        } else {
            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    baseSetStartDelayMs(0);
                    try {
                        startImpl();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // fail silently for a state exception when it is happening after
                        // a delayed start, as the player state could have changed between the
                        // call to start() and the execution of startImpl()
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

If performance is of concern with Code A, then MediaPlayerHolder.loadMedia(String path) is where a separate Thread should be used.

So to answer your question. No, you do not need to run MediaPlayer in a Service. It depends on your requirements.

Regards